# Distinguishing between Chrome OS apps and Android apps

Tags: android, chromebook, google-chrome-os

I have two versions installed for several apps on my Chromebook, an Android version and a Chrome OS version, e.g. Gmail. How can I identify what type of app I'm selecting?

Is it possible to do so within the launcher/search bar? What about in the master list of apps after pressing the up arrow?

[image: Illustration of duplicate apps]

Comment: I'm baffled at the closure of this question. How is this about anything other than "computer software and personal and home computer networking," two of the three items in the "on-topic guidelines?

Comment: The use of the tag "Android" is the likely reason why your question was closed. Your question is not about Android, it is about Chrome apps, one of which is tangentially related to Android. The Tag Guidance should be reviewed for any tags you use to help choose whether they are appropriate on a given question or not.

Comment: @music2myear it's about both Android and Chrome apps; specifically between distinguishing between them on Chrome OS.

Comment: It's for an app written for Android, not for the Android OS. As I stated, you should read the tag guidance.

Comment: @music2myear if Android didn't exist, glenviewjeff and I wouldn't have this problem. Therefore it is "crucial to your question" (quoting the "tag guidance"). It's not "for an app written for Android" - it's for all Android apps installed into Chrome OS, and the common factor for them all is the Android OS. The tags are appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears only to be a roundabout workaround to distinguish between the two. In the search bar, you can right-click on the application and select "uninstall." If the dialog box includes the option to "also clear browsing data," then it's apparently the Chrome app. Otherwise it's the Android application.

[image: Screennshot]